# Update a dynamic loaded field

Tags: reactjs

When the page is loaded there is no any dynamic fields visible yet. After clicking on the `Load Dynamic Field` button; a dynamic field gets visible with the default value of the state field `name ("Old Name")`.

I expect to get this dynamic field updated with the text `New Name` when I click on the `Update Field` button since it updates the `name` field but it doesn't.

Why doesn't it get updated? How can I solve this?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-sound-tikdu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

**Code**

```
interface State {
    dynamicFields: JSX.Element[];
    name: string;
}
export default class Page extends React.Component<{}, State> {
    public constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dynamicFields: [],
            name: "Old Name"
        };
    }

    private updateField = () => {
        this.setState({ name: "New Name" });
    };

    public loadField = () => {
        const fields = [<div key={Math.random()}>{this.state.name}</div>];
        this.setState({ dynamicFields: [...fields] });
    };

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.loadField}>Load Dynamic Field</button>
                <button onClick={this.updateField}>Update Field</button>

                {this.state.dynamicFields &&
                this.state.dynamicFields.map(block => block)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing the updated `state.dynamicFields` with the latest value of `state.name` is because you're not updating `state.dynamicFields` after you update `state.name`, so it uses the old value of `state.name`.

The value of `state.dynamicField` never changes when you update `state.name`, so it will stay the same. What you would want is to call `updateField` and then `loadField` again so that `state.dynamicFields` are recreated using the latest value of `state.name`.

`React` won't know to update `state.dynamicFields` after you update `state.name`, so it will not update/re-render components that are stored in a `state`. In this case it is your responsibility to create a new array that contains elements which use the latest value of `state.name` and update `state.dynamicFields`.

Here's a slightly modified example that works as expected and I think is a better approach in this situation:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dynamicFields: [],
    name: `old name`
  };

  updateField = () => {
    this.setState({
      name: `new name ${Math.random()}`
    });
  };

  renderDynamicFields = () => {
    return this.state.dynamicFields.map((_, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>{this.state.name}</div>
    ));
  };

  updateDynamicFields = () => {
    this.setState({
      dynamicFields: Array.from({ length: 2 }).map((_, idx) => idx)
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.updateDynamicFields}>Load/update dynamic field</button>
        <button onClick={this.updateField}>Update field</button>

        {this.renderDynamicFields()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I thought it more like; if a binded state field value changes which is in our case `name`, then the react it should update the binded components implicitly?

Comment: @KorkiKorkig That'd apply if you're rendering them directly in the `render` method. Instead what you're doing is utilizing `state.dynamicFields` to save an array with elements that use `state.name`, so it is your responsibility to update/re-render those elements if they rely on another piece of `state`. `React` doesn't know to update `state.B` because you updated `state.A` - they not dependent on each other.

Comment: Indeed, React cannot know which element to update in state changes with dynamic components, but unless you use `key`? Or it is still the same situation; if you don't render them directly, React cannot update them, you should do it yourself.. ?

Comment: @KorkiKorkig If you render them inside of the `render` method they are still dynamic. The issue is that you want `React` to update `state.B` because `state.A` changed - this will not work. You're responsible for updating these elements because you decided to handle the rendering yourself by storing them in an `array` in your `state`. `key` won't help here because you created a "custom" behavior.